# migrate.exe could not load entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to use migrate.exe locally before setting it up on my build server, but I can't even run the help command `/?` without getting the error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've been browsing around for solutions, coming across [Microsoft's migrate.exe getting started page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx) among other things, but haven't been able to solve this.

I've tried copying the migrate.exe file into my projects `/bin/Debug` folder alongside the project's dll and the entity framework dll, but I continue to see this error (screenshot showing it below).

I've also verified the version of the dll for entity framework, and it is indeed `6.0.0.0`. I'm using nuget to include entity framework, and I'm currently using `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />`.

Any recommendations or help is much appreciated!

[image: proof that I'm copying the migrate.exe file into my projects /bin/Debug directory]

Comment: About 10 seconds after posting, I loaded up a separate non-VS powershell command prompt and tried with success, so it seems that this may be a 32/64bit issue with a misleading error? If so, is there a way to embed a 64bit PS prompt in VS?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the right EF assemblies for your .NET version?.

My app is generated with .NET 4.5, so I use the assemblies **EntityFramework.dll** and **EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll** from *\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net45* and **migrate.exe** from *\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\tools*.

Try to use absolute path for **startUpDirectory** and **startUpConfigurationFile** arguments.

For example:

```
migrate.exe MyAssembly.dll /startUpDirectory="C:\MyApp\bin" /startUpConfigurationFile="C:\MyApp\App.config"
```

HTH

Comment: I had a similar situation. This answer prompted me to try copying the EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll from my bin\release folder into the same path as migrate.exe. That resolved the core problem so that migrate.exe (from the package\...\tools directory) is no longer failing.

Comment: This worked for me. I threw migrate.exe into my bin directory and executed there. No problems.